# Matching key names and values of two lists

Tags: python

How can I create a dictionary of similarly named values in two lists?

```
color = ['blue','red','orange',.........]

color_variation = ['blue_0121', 'sea_blue', 'red_0234', 'red_light', 'orange_0120', .........]
```

The resulting dictionary should look like:

```
color_dict = {'blue':['blue_0121', 'sea_blue'], 'red': ['red_0234', 'red_light'], 'orange': ['orange_0120'], 'purple': [..........]}
```

I tried with:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(color, color_variation) if "{}".format(k) in v}
```

How can I match the values to be assigned to the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a dictionary-comprehension:

```
{c: [v for v in color_variation if c in v] for c in color}
```

**Example**:

```
color = ['blue','red','orange']
color_variation = ['blue_0121', 'sea_blue', 'red_0234', 'red_light', 'orange_0120']

print({c: [v for v in color_variation if c in v] for c in color})
# {'blue': ['blue_0121', 'sea_blue'], 'red': ['red_0234', 'red_light'], 'orange': ['orange_0120']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use here [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = defaultdict(list)

for c in color:
     for color_var in color_variation:
         if c in color_var:
             l[c].append(color_var)
```

and `l` is

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'blue': ['blue_0121', 'sea_blue'],
             'red': ['red_0234', 'red_light'],
             'orange': ['orange_0120']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `itertools.groupby()`:

```py
import itertools

colors=["red", "blue","green","orange"]
color_variation=["baby-blue","light orange","burgundy red","greenwich green","darkish green", "red567","navy blue","grapefruit red"]
keyfunc=lambda x: next(c for c in colors if c in x)

color_variation=sorted(color_variation, key=keyfunc)
res={k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(color_variation, keyfunc)}

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
{'blue': ['baby-blue', 'navy blue'], 'green': ['greenwich green', 'darkish green'], 'orange': ['light orange'], 'red': ['burgundy red', 'red567', 'grapefruit red']}

[Program finished]
```